# Changing value of specific dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary

So the problem is following:
I have dictionary which looks like this

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> Stats
```

For visualisation:

```
"Stats":{
            "1":{
               "True":0,
               "False":0
            },
            "2":{
               "True":0,
               "False":0
            }
        }
```

So what I want to do is to change value of "True" where key is "1". My code looks like this :

```
CurrentStats.Stats["1"]["True"] += 1;
```

But it changes "True" value of both key "1" and key "2". How can I fix this and why does it change both values?

```
public async Task<IStatistics> CreateStats()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> stats = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
        Dictionary<string, int> dt = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dt.Add("True", 0);
        dt.Add("False", 0);
        var topics = new TopicServices();
        foreach (var item in (await topics.GetTopics()).ToList())
        {
            stats.Add(item.id, dt);
        }
        var st = new Statistics() { Stats = stats };

        return st;
    }
```

this is the function i use to initialize the dictionary

Comment: Please show how you initialised the dictionary. The answer probably lies there.

Comment: thanks for replay, I added the function i used, but its a little bit complicated as i use read value to initialize it and then return the object which has the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you initialise the nested dictionary, you only initialised one inner dictionary and just added that *same one* into the outer dictionary twice:

```
    // only one "new Dictionary" is created below
    Dictionary<string, int> dt = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dt.Add("True", 0);
    dt.Add("False", 0);
    var topics = new TopicServices();
    foreach (var item in (await topics.GetTopics()).ToList())
    {
        stats.Add(item.id, dt); // that same dictionary is added to the outer dictionary many times
    }
```

So `CurrentStats.Stats["1"]` and `CurrentStats.Stats["2"]` actually refer to the same `Dictionary` object.

To fix this, you need to create a new dictionary each time, simply move the dictionary-creating code inside the loop:

```
    var topics = new TopicServices();
    foreach (var item in (await topics.GetTopics()).ToList())
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dt = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dt.Add("True", 0);
        dt.Add("False", 0);
        stats.Add(item.id, dt);
    }
```

Comment: You nailed that with the initialization comment